# Don't reload ajax content on back press

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm currently loading a post list with infinite scroll functionality. I'm loading a small popup that has title and content in dynamic ajax popup. When the article is clicked, the URL changes to website.com/news/newsID. Now, when I press the back button, the ajax post list reloads from the beginning. I want to preserve whatever ajax is loaded already so that when pressing the browser back button, I want it to look like a close button is clicked.
Currently my ajax loading of post is something like this:
:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: true,
    type: 'GET',
    url: window.location.origin + '/' + newsId ,
    dataType: 'html',

    beforeSend: function() {
        //here the popUp UI is loading
    },

    success: function(data) {
//here the popUp UI is replaced with data
    },

  });
```

And the ajax for infinite scroll is something like this:

```
function ajaxget_Stories(postappendID, isPaginated) {
    $.ajax(
      {
        cache: true,
        type: 'GET',
        url: window.location.origin + location.pathname,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
          $('#' + postappendID).empty();
          var data = JSON.parse(data);
          $('#' + postappendID).append(data.html);

        },
      
        async: true,
      },
      0
    );
  
  }
```

Both of the ajax is working fine. Expect the functionality I need is not.
What I'm looking for is something like this:

1. Popup close on back button. I've a event/function available for closing popup.
2. Preserve old ajax infinite scrolled content when pressing back after loading the content.
3. Revert the URL to previous one when pressing the back button.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: the browser cache will do all the magic for you. don't care for the additional request,  keep your code simple.

Comment: @philipp what do you think is making code complicated? The current code is not doing any "magic". Elaboration on how I can achieve it? Thank you

Comment: Just saying that you do not need to take care of caching the response from the server. The browser will cache all that and you can safely reload over and over again.